# Instruct getUserMedia to use best available camera resolution

Tags: javascript, html, video, getusermedia

I am using the getUserMedia function to record video from a webcam. Everyting works fine, except that it was only recording in 640x480 resolution, when I just specified video: true for the constraint.

If I set the constraint as below, I now get better quality recording on my laptop:

```
var mediaConstraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: {
        width: { min: 1280 },
        height: { min: 720 }
    }
};
```

But what if another device is capable of better than 1280x720, or has even lower capabilities?

I tried playing around with setting min to be very low, and max to be very high; but it just defaulted to 640x480, or gave nothing at all. I also tried setting the desired size, but as expected - I just ended up with whatever that value was. If I set desired to be very high (so it would choose the closest available), I ended up with nothing.

So the question is, how to set the constraints to get whatever the maximum resolution a camera can provide?

Answer (score 3):

Note that `min` means "minimum allowed value", and since most browsers default to 640x480, values lower than that wont have much effect.

According to the spec, just ask for a high resolution, and you should get the closest resolution the camera can produce. E.g.:

```
var mediaConstraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: { width: 2880, height: 1800 }
};
```

This works in Firefox, and may work in Edge too (which I haven't tried).

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282385/webrtc-firefox-constraints/28911694#28911694) for more on why this works.

Chrome (though they are working on it) still relies on the [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) polyfill for the standard constraints syntax unfortunately, and that polyfill has some limitations, like the one you are running into here.

If you are using [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter), you can look in the web console in Chrome to see the old non-standard syntax that it uses natively. Using that syntax it is possible to construct a series of successively broader min-ranges, and getting the algorithm to prefer higher values that way.